# Задача по информатике

Tags: ассемблер, информатика

Никак я не могу решить эту задачу. В голову совсем ничего не приходит. :(

> У вас есть два 16 битных регистра R1 и R2, для представления
>   отрицательных чисел используется дополнение до 2. В регистре R1
>   хранится число X не равное нулю. Вы записали в регистр R2 значение -X
>   и оказалось, что значения в регистрах R1 и R2 равны. Найдите число X.

Задача от [сюда](https://stepic.org/lesson/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-13481/step/11?course=%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%AD%D0%92%D0%9C-%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC&unit=3637).

Comment: [`System.Int16.MinValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int16.minvalue.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При использовании дополнения до двух для представления отрицательных чисел, половина представимых чисел в регистре фиксированной разрядности будут отрицательными, а половина неотрицательными. И так как к неотрицательным числам относится нуль, то получается, что представимых отрицательных чисел будет на одно больше чем представимых положительных. То есть существует такое отрицательное число, обратное к которому не представимо в регистре такой же разрядности. Собственно это число `X=10000000000000002` и будет единственным кандидатом для условия `-X=X, X≠0`. В том, что данное число удовлетворяет условию, легко убедится, проведя операцию обращения согласно правилам дополнения до двух: обратить все биты (`01111111111111112`) и прибавить единицу (`10000000000000002`).

Comment: Отличное объяснение, все понятно. Единственное, почему-то не проходит проверку. Ссылку на сайт с тестом добавил к вопросу.

Comment: @faoxis Я ввожу `-32768` и мне показывает, что ответ верный.

Comment: Поторопился и ввел в двоичной системе...